# Can a subset of the plane have nontrivial $H_2$ or $\pi_2$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, counterexamples

This is a question that occurred to me years ago when I was first learning algebraic topology.  I've since learned that it's a somewhat aesthetically displeasing question, but I'm still curious about the answer.

Is it possible for a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ to have a nontrivial singular homology group $H_2$?  What about a nontrivial homotopy group $\pi_2$?

Comment: I assume you're looking for pathological examples. By Alexander duality, $H_2$ must be trivial if the subset is compact and locally contractible.

Comment: Read the introduction in http://www.imfm.si/preprinti/PDF/00863.pdf.

Comment: The link to the preprint cited by Igor Belegradek is now here http://preprinti.imfm.si/PDF/00863.pdf

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Apparently the asphericity is due to Zastrow (see [Cannon-Conner-Zastrow](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101000050#)).

Also apparently the result that the higher homology groups vanish is [due to Zastrow](https://mat.ug.edu.pl/~zastrow/nonanorn.ps), but his habilitation thesis never seems to have appeared.

Comment: Thanks for finding the link to Zastrow's revised paper. I found a page of his which links to both the old and new versions and briefly describes the differences https://mat.ug.edu.pl/~zastrow/Nnonano.htm . Versions of his Habilitationsschrift are also available here http://homepage.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/Andreas.Zastrow/pitriv.htm

Answer (score 69):

The higher-dimensional analog has the surprising answer "yes".  Namely, for $n\geq 2$, the $n$-dimensional Hawaiian earring $H_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty   S(k)$, where $S(k)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is the $n$-sphere with center ${1\over 2k}\mathbf{e}_1$ and radius ${1\over 2k}$ has nonzero homology in arbitrarily high dimensions.  This is a result of Barratt and Milnor ([An Example of Anomalous Singular Homology](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9/home.html)).