# Homology groups of compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, homology

I am working over the paper: [Target Enumeration via Euler Characteristic Integrals](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/070687293) and in order to follow a proof I need to prove:

> If $A$ is compact nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the singular homology
>   groups of $A$, $H_k(A)$ vanish for $k\geq 2$.

The result seems seems reasonable for me (there are non obvious counterexamples in dimension grater than three but not in dimension two). But I am having difficulties finding a proof.

What I have tried or thought so far:

- Using the long exact sequence in homology and it didn't work.
- Maybe trying luck with de Rham cohomology and using some kind of isomorphism followed by the Universal Coefficients theorem in cohomology....
- Using some dimension theory but I have no clue how...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Please** do not ask the same question here and on math.stackexchange.coom at the same time. Please delete this one and if we have to we will *move* the other one here.

Comment: Link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162579/homology-groups-of-compact-subset-of-mathbbr2 . Unlike Mariano I'd rather suggest you erase the MathSE question and leave it here.

Comment: Well, I took the time to add a couple of comments, chase a reference and explain why two of the ideas have no chance of working *there*. There *is* a reason why we do not like double posting, and it is precisely that: wasted and duplicated effort.

Comment: As I said in the other post, there **are obvious** counterexamples in dimension $\ge 2$: the 2-sphere. To be a counterexample, it is enough to have $H_2\neq 0$. Mariano mentioned more fancy counterexamples, with subsets of the 3-space with nonvanishing higher homology groups.

Comment: A related fact: $\pi_i$ of planar sets (with basepoints) vanishes for $i\ge 2$: *Cannon, Conner, Zastrow, One-dimensional sets and planar sets are aspherical.
Topology Appl. 120 (2002), no. 1-2, 23-45*. (MR link: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1895481; ScienceDirect link: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101000050.

Comment: See also this older question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/189323/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered in the paper

> *The singular homology group of planar sets do not behave anomalously* 
>   by Andreas Zastrow

This appears to be a link to the paper:  http://at.yorku.ca/i/d/e/b/11.htm

Comment: It's not an argument :) Anyway we can erase all these obsolete comments now.